# D3 interpolated points not intersecting at the correct positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an issue where I want to draw a series of equally spaced (24px in this case) vertical lines on my graph. I want to find the point where these vertical lines intersect a path and then draw a circle at each point of intersection.

The vertical lines are rendering fine but I think I must be doing something wrong when attempting to render the circles at the point of intersection.

[Full Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gXxTsC?p=preview)

```
function drawVerticalLinesAndIntersectionPoints(){
  let bisect = d3.bisector(d => d['time']).right;

  for (var i = radius; i < width; i += (radius*2)) {
    // The datapoint that intersects the line at i (this x distance in pixels)
    var item = dataset[bisect(dataset, x.invert(i).getTime())];

    this.svg.append('g')
      .append('line')
      .attr('x1', i)
      .attr('y1', 0)
      .attr('x2', i)
      .attr('y2', height)
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("stroke-dasharray", "5, 5")
      .style("stroke", "black");

    // Draw the item circle which should be at the point where the vertical dashed line interesects the graph line
    // `item` does not appear to contain a time that corresponds to i (this x distance in pixels)
    addDataPointElement(item);
  }
}

function addDataPointElement(dataPoint) {
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'data-point')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(dataPoint.time) + "," + y(dataPoint.value) + ")")
      .append('circle')
        .attr('r', radius)
        .style("stroke", 'red')
        .style("fill", 'none');
}
```

Comment: Since your vertical lines are equally spaced and your data points are not, it seems obvious, that the circles, representing these data points won't necessarily be located on those lines.

Comment: What you are looking for is not that trivial a task. Have a look at: [*"Find intersection of SVG path"*](/q/26490861), [*"How do I return y coordinate of a path in d3.js?"*](/q/12431595) and [*"Get point's y coordinate on svg path"*](/q/22633718), as well as this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578146/get-y-coordinate-of-point-along-svg-path-with-given-an-x-coordinate#comment22084485_15578146).

Comment: @altocumulus Thanks. My understanding was that my `bisector` would return the interpolated `time` and `value` on the path at the given time (`x.invert(i).getTime()`). If it's not doing this can you tell me what the results for `item.time` and `item.value` actually correspond to?

Comment: The bisector itself won't do any interpolations. It is used to calculate a position in an array. Because you are using a *right* bisector, it will return the position of the array's elment, comparing the property `time`, which follows the element having its property `time` as `x.invert(i).getTime()`.

Comment: Which lets me follow-up on my first comment: Do you really want the circles to be centered on the lines, i.e. independent of your data points, or would you rather want the lines to match the data points like the circles do, i.e. have them drawn *not* equally spaced?

Comment: Yes, in this scenario I do. This is part of a larger piece of functionality which groups overlapping datapoints (circles) into a single circle with with text identifying how many datapoints are included in this circle.

Comment: Then you are going to have to calculate the y-coordinate at that position by some method described in the resources I linked to in my above [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477405/d3-interpolated-points-not-intersecting-at-the-correct-positions?noredirect=1#comment64357935_38477405).

Comment: Thanks @altocumulus. Think I've got it sorted now http://plnkr.co/edit/gXxTsC?p=preview

Comment: Looks nice. If there is something new to learn for the rest of us, please put your approach into an answer. If you did just apply some method already described in the linked to posts, you might consider deleting this question altogether.

Comment: Marked it as a duplicate given that I think the extended discussion is pretty useful